# Messaging menu turn blue for no reason

Tags: notification, pidgin, messaging-menu

I expect the "envelope" from the messaging menu to turn blue only where there is a pending notification (like a new mail or a new IM message). When I click it, I usually see from which app the notification come from.

Sometime, the envelope turn blue, but there is no notification. When I click the envelope, I don't see any app with notifications pending. I can "clean" the notifications to change the color to white, but the envelope will turn blue again after some minutes.

The only solution I found is to reboot the computer...

Is it a known bug? There is a way to get the application that send this notification? I didn't find anything about that after a Google search.

- I still didn't find way to get a "debug view" of the messaging menu.  I found dbus-monitor but this just spam too much and I can't find anything useful from that.
- Seem like I'm missing some messages from Pidgin (xmpp).  I'm thinking that the messaging icon become blue to warn me a new message was received, but Pidgin fails to show me that message.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the problem.  Even if I already uninstalled empathy app, the framework telepathy was still running in the background, so I had 2 connections opened on the xmpp server...